# Fuzzy string matching and term frequency in Solr

Tags: solr

Solr can return the term frequency for a given term with the function query termfreq(*field*, 'term'). However, as far as I know, you can not get the term frequency for fuzzy matches; you can not write termfreq(*field*, 'term~1') to get the term frequency for all terms within the Levenshtein distance of 1.

For example, given that I have two documents, 1 and 2, where document 1 contains 'cats' two times, and document 2 contains 'carts' one time and run the query: `q=cats~1&fl=id,freq: termfreq(text, cats)`, the response would look like something like this:

```
{'response': {'docs':
 [{'id': 1, 'freq': 2},
  {'id': 2, 'freq': 0}]
  ...
}
```

What I would want is that the term frequency of the terms that the search have been expanded to is included in the term frequency, such that the response would be something like:

```
{'response': {'docs':
 [{'id': 1, 'freq': 2},
  {'id': 2, 'freq': 1}]
  ...
}
```

Is there any way to do this, or something along the lines of this, in a relatively easy way in Solr?

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do this in Solr is pre-processing the different combinations of the query term and use this to look up the term frequencies.